# Angular [Violation] Dom Mutation warnings in Chrome

Tags: javascript, angular, google-chrome, console, warnings

In our Angular 6 project, in Chrome, I'm suddenly noticing these `[Violation]` warnings in our app stemming from `zone.js` line 1666. The message:

`[Violation] Added synchronous DOM mutation listener to a 'DOMNodeInserted' event. Consider using MutationObserver to make the page more responsive.`

I've never seen these before, but then again they're in a Chrome dev tools tab I've never noticed before (the `console sidebar`). When I switched over to an older branch and locally served it, these warnings still appear. So perhaps these warnings have always been there and I missed it all this time, or perhaps a merge with a teammate's project changed a file in Angular permanently, causing further builds to always cause these warnings.

I checked line 1666 of zone.js and it involves the following code:

```
    var customScheduleGlobal = function () {
        // if there is already a task for the eventName + capture,
        // just return, because we use the shared globalZoneAwareCallback here.
        if (taskData.isExisting) {
            return;
        }
        return nativeAddEventListener.call(taskData.target, taskData.eventName, taskData.capture ? globalZoneAwareCaptureCallback : globalZoneAwareCallback, taskData.options);
    };
```

To my knowledge we've never modified zone.js. What are these `[Violation]` warnings, how can I fix them, consequences of not fixing them?

Comment: Check to see if your chrome console has been switched to Verbose mode. If that is the case then you can likely just ignore the warning. Verbose warnings are more hints / tips than critical issues.

Answer (score 0):

You are using MutationObserver at somewhere of your project. You should destroy it when you dont need anymore.

```
export class Somedirective implements OnDestroy
    this.changes = new MutationObserver(....)

    ngOnDestroy(){
        this.changes.disconnect();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The errors you mentioned may occur due to the jQuery version. Therefore, I recommend updating the jQuery version first.

If you're still getting errors, you should edit the **app.component.ts** file in the project like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'angular-web-ui';

  ngOnInit() {
    this.detectDivChanges();
  }

  detectDivChanges() {
    const div = document.querySelector('.container')!;
    const config = { attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true };
    const observer = new MutationObserver((mutation) => {
      console.log("it works. enjoy :)");
    })
    observer.observe(div, config);
  }
}
```

If this method also didn't fix the problem, I'm sure that it depends on running extensions. An extension coded using an old version of jQuery and listening for DOM mutations will cause this issue.

The quickest way to find out if this is the cause of the problem is to also run the project in incognito mode.